# How can I scan over sets of rows in HappyBase with a single API call?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, bigtable, happybase

I want to scan a big-table for a list of IDs (or prefixes of IDs) (using Python HappyBase).

Is there any way to do it on server side? That is, I'd like to send a list of start/stop rows to be scanned in one API call rather than performing a long series of API calls.

Here's an example. For my_big_tables keys:

```
2019/1
2019/2
2019/3
...
2020/1
2020/2
2020/3
2020/4
..
```

In one query, I'd like to get all the records from months 1 and 2 for all years. The results should be:

```
2019/1
2019/2
2020/1
2020/2
```

Comment: Thank you for awarding the bounty! Could you please mark the answer as solved, if it worked for you?

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using the `row_start` and `row_stop` arguments in Table.scan(), this may be a better fit for the `filter` argument with a regular expression.

See the [API reference](https://google-cloud-python-happybase.readthedocs.io/en/latest/happybase-table.html#google.cloud.happybase.table.Table.scan) for details on the filter argument:

> The keyword argument `filter` is also supported (beyond column and row
>   range filters supported here). HappyBase / HBase users will have used
>   this as an HBase filter string. (See the [Thrift docs](http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/book/thrift.html) for more details
>   on those filters.) However, Google Cloud Bigtable doesn’t support
>   those filter strings so a `RowFilter` should be used instead.

RowFilter is a type provided by Google's Bigtable library. [Here are the docs](https://google-cloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/0.32.0/bigtable/row-filters.html). Assuming that the ID field you're referring to is your row key, we can use [RowKeyRegexFilter](https://google-cloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/0.32.0/bigtable/row-filters.html#google.cloud.bigtable.row_filters.RowKeyRegexFilter) to filter the IDs by the pattern you've described.

We'll start by coming up with a regular expression to match a list of IDs for the desired months. For example, if you wanted to filter year-based IDs for the months of December and January, you could use this (note that you must go from the largest number to the shortest) -- see [this link](https://regex-golang.appspot.com/assets/html/index.html) to test the regular expression:

```
\d\d\d\d\/(12|1)
```

Here's an attempt to write a function that creates a Google Bigtable HappyBase scan call with an appropriate filter, where `table` is a HappyBase table and `months` is a list of integers. Please note that I have **not** tested this code, but hopefully it at least gives you a starting point.

```
from google.cloud.bigtable.row_filters import RowKeyRegexFilter

def filter_by_months(table, months):
    months_reversed = sorted(months, reverse=True)
    months_strings = [str(month) for month in months_reversed]
    months_joined = "|".join(months_strings)

    key_filter = RowKeyRegexFilter('\d\d\d\d\/({})'.format(months_joined))
    return table.scan(filter=key_filter)
```